# Regex for Two Tag Find & Replace

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

Fellow Forum Members,
I am using the latest version of NotePad++. I would be very grateful if anyone out there can help me develop a Regex that performs an opening & closing tag find & replace operation depending on whether or not the opening tag being replaced is preceded by an opening `<levelledPara>` tag.  Below is example code to clarify what I need the Regex to do:

FIND THIS TEXT STRING:
`<levelledPara><title>THIS IS TEXT FOR A TITLE</title>`

REPLACE WITH THIS TEXT STRING:
`<levelledPara><para>THIS IS TEXT FOR A TITLE</para>`

To summarize,  I need the `<title>` and `</title>` tags replaced with `<para>` and `</para>` only when the opening `<title>` tag is preceded by an opening `<levelledPara>` tag. In addition, I need the text within the `<para>` and `</para>` tags to remain unchanged.  Is it possible for a Regex to perform such an operation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex for search based on **captured groups**:

```
(<levelledPara>\s*)<([^>]+)>(.*?)<\/\2>
```

And use this replacement:

```
$1<para>$3</para>
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jT7lF0/4)

**Regex breakup:**

```
(<levelledPara>\s*) # Match <levelledPara> followed by 0 or more spaces and group it ($1)
<([^>]+)>           # Match a XML tag and group it ($2)
(.*?)               # Match 0 or more characters (non-greedy) and group it ($3)
<\/\2>              # Match closing tag using back-reference to captured group #2
```

Replacement it:

```
$1       # Back-reference of captured group #1
<para>   # Literal text <para>
$3       # Back-reference of captured group #1
</para>  # Literal text </para>
```

Comment: Anubhava, you are a gentleman and scholar. What I find interesting about your RegEx is how it has no need to include the "title tag" as part of the find and replace operation.  I will test it out and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the below one working too. In the find box keep:

```
                <levelledPara><title>(.*)</title>
```

and in the replace box keep

```
                <levelledPara><para>\1</para>
```

Hope this works in your case too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex you can solve this issue by find "**title>**" and replace it with "**para>**"